# New Forest Role before installation on bareboned Exchange 2019

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, exchange-server

I'm at the stage of prep where I'm adding DNS and AD role through GUI, and I'm stuck at the "new forest" part.  I'm tempted to just put in another fictional .local name. On the other hand, I might be making a fatal error.

I'm also wondering if SMTP will need to follow an article I found saying set that up with localhost anyway.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By simply adding "lab" into my search criteria of "exchange 2019" I'm seeing using .local is accepted practice.